# Android Save stepcounter sensor value

Tags: android, count, text-files, android-sensors

I am creating a simple application using Androids new Sensors.

I have created a simple pedometer which counts steps but now i want to manipulate it by retrieving the most recent value and saving that value to a text file.

This code outputs the sensor value.

How can i retrieve whatever value is outputed on the screen to store in a text file on a button click, such as save?

Thanks!

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (activityRunning) {
        steps.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[0]));

    }
```

Comment: If you want to grab the current value, use steps.getText().toString().

Comment: Cheers, completely forgot about that! haha